# Mocked object not passing to the other class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm making a mock class of istream to test a class. But the mocked object is not passing to the actual class i want to use in.

This is the mock class.

```
class MockStream{
 private:
std::string filename_;

public:
MockStream(){


}
MockStream(std::string filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out):filename_(filename){

}
MockStream(const MockStream &a){}
MockStream& operator=(const MockStream& a){
  return *this;
}
~MockStream(){}
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(is_open,bool());
MOCK_METHOD0(close,void());
MOCK_METHOD2(read,MockStream&(char*,std::streamsize));
MOCK_METHOD2(write,MockStream&(const char*,std::streamsize));
MOCK_METHOD2(seekg,MockStream&(std::streamoff,std::ios_base::seekdir));
MOCK_METHOD1(seekg,MockStream&(std::streampos));
MOCK_METHOD0(get_filename,std::string());



};
```

test:

```
TEST(random_access_stack, mocked_test)
{
RandomAccessStack<TestClass,u_int64_t,MockStream>              stack;
MockStream  mocked; 


EXPECT_CALL(mocked,is_open()).Times(1).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

stack.SetStream(mocked); 
EXPECT_TRUE(stack.is_open());


}
```

SetStream function:

```
void SetStream(STREAM& handle){
file_handle_ = handle;
}
```

where file_handle_ is of type MockStream passed by template

The output is:

```
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: is_open()
          Returns: false
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
/build/libs/storage/tests/gtest/random_access_stack_tests.cpp:79: Failure
Value of: stack.is_open()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
/build/libs/storage/tests/gtest/random_access_stack_tests.cpp:73: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mocked, is_open())...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Comment: where do you expect `mocked.is_open()` to be called? inside `stack.is_open()`?

Comment: @MikevanDyke yes. Copying the mocked object in `file_handle_` , then calling its `is_open()` in `stack.is_open()`

Comment: and `file_handle_` is of type `MockStream` or is it a reference to the `MockStream`-object `mocked`?

Comment: @MikevanDyke yes, its of type      MockStream

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL` is invoked on the `mocked` object, but `is_open()` is called on the object `file_handle_`. As those are 2 different objects (and are located on different memory locations), `EXPECT_CALL` is not satisfied.